# Why the form is not being saved into the database?

Tags: python, postgresql, django-forms, django-2.2

I've been stuck on this for a while, can't seem to fix this. I've checked the code a hundred times but obviously there is something I'm missing.
I have 1 form for create new user, connect everything into the database (PostgreSQL), but the form doesn't save. I'm trying to create new user, then when it's successful, to render it into users.html
Can anybody say what I'm missing?

**models.py**

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):

    email                   = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username                = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    name                    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_joined             = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date_joined", auto_now_add=True)
    last_login              = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="last_login", auto_now=True)
    is_admin                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active               = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser            = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    profile_image           = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to=get_profile_image_filepath, null=True, blank=True, default=get_default_profile_image)
```

**forms.py**

```
class AccountForm(UserCreationForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=255, help_text="Required. Add a valid email address")
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        ('1', 'admin'),
        ('2', 'reception'),
        ('3', 'headofdepartment'),
        ('4', 'employee'),
        ('5', 'patient'),
        ('6', 'inactive'),
        )
    role = forms.ChoiceField(choices = ROLE_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = [
            'email', 
            'name',
            'role'
            ]
        labels = {
            'name': 'Име',
            'password': 'Парола',
            'role': 'Роля',
        }
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email'].lower()
        try:
            account = Account.objects.get(email=email)
        except Exception as e:
            return email
        raise forms.ValidationError(f"Email {email} is already in used")
```

views.py

```
def users(request):
     accounts = Account.objects.all()
     context = {'accounts': accounts}
     return render(request, 'users.html', context)
    
def users_add(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    print(request.POST)
    form = AccountForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        form = Account(email=email, name=name)
        form.save()
    return render(request, 'users.html', {})
else:
    return render(request, 'useradd.html', {
        'form': AccountForm(),
    })
```

**Settings.py:**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'feedback',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

useradd.html

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}


    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-10.offset-md-1 mt-5">
          <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 class="display-4">Добавяне на нов потребител</h1>
            <hr class="my-4">
             <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <table>
                {{ form.as_table }}
                  </table>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Запиши <i class="far fa-save"></i></button>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


{% endblock content %}
```

urls.py

```
path('users/', views.users, name="users"), # Get request to retrieve and display users
path('users/add', views.users_add, name="useradd"),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some "action" in your useradd.html  tag I think you should use this

```
<form action="{% url 'users_add' %}" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

Edit:

Try making your views.py look like this:

```py
def users_add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AccountForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return render(request, 'useradd.html', {})
    else:
        return render(request, 'users.html', {
            'form': AccountForm(),
        })
```

Edit 2:
Try adding some cleaning before you save it.

```py
def users_add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AccountForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            #Add all of the fields here and then add them bellow into the acc variable
            acc = Account(email=email, username=username, name=name)
            acc.save()
        return render(request, 'useradd.html', {})
```

Comment: I add this to my useradd.html but still doesn't save into the postgres database

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your answer. Could you please check it again. Also my models.py is imported in my views.py

Comment: I changed it, so that it's more understandable, is it okay like this?

Comment: I edit my question. In views.py I printed the result, and it's printed in the terminal. But why isn't save into the database

Comment: Still doesn't save... Should I provide more information about models or database, idk can't understand where is the problem

Comment: Edited my answer again, what about now?

Comment: Submit the form successful, it's printed in the terminal, but again not saved in the database